# How do I make multiple SQL queries in one statement (with Node)?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I've looked up a lot of sources to get to this point in my multiple query statement, but am now stuck. How does one make multiple queries in one statement to a SQL database? Here's where I have for my game database..

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    const search = req.query.search;
    var json = {};

    var sql_query = "SELECT * FROM item_template i WHERE i.name LIKE '" + "%" + search + "%" + "' ORDER BY i.Quality DESC, i.name ASC; SELECT c.Entry, c.Name, c.MinLevel, c.MaxLevel, c.CreatureType FROM creature_template c WHERE c.name LIKE '" + "%" + search + "%" + "' ORDER BY c.name ASC; SELECT q.Title, q.entry, q.MinLevel, q.QuestLevel, q.RequiredRaces FROM quest_template q WHERE q.Title LIKE '" + "%" + search + "%" + "' ORDER BY q.QuestLevel ASC";

    var result = connection.query(sql_query, function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        json["items"] = result[0];
        json["creatures"] = result[1];
        json["quests"] = result[2];
        console.log("Sent JSON to client");
        res.send(JSON.stringify(json));
    });
})
```

I get this error in my Node terminal:

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT c.Entry, c.Name, c.MinLevel, c.MaxLevel, c.CreatureType FROM creature_tem' at line 1

Comment: Looks like with the NPM mySQL package you're using, you have to specifically enable multiple statements (for security reasons). Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#multiple-statement-queries. I also warn you that the query shown is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack, since you're not parameterizing the string inputs.

Comment: I had been doing that but with the 'M' of multipleStatements capitalized. This fixed it!